# NullReferenceException with referenced Control in ContentPresenter from custom UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I created a **custom UserControl** (SlideControl), containing a ContentPresenter (Property name: PageContent). On my page I use the UserControl and add some Xaml to the PageContent.
One of the controls there has a name (testTb). When I access the testTb in the code behind it is recognized at compile time. At run time I get a **NullReferenceException**.

What can I do?

This is what I have:

**SlideControl.xaml:**

```
<Canvas>
    <!-- some style here I want to use on every app page (slide in menu) -->
    <ContentPresenter Name="PageContentPresenter" />
</Canvas>
```

**SlideControl.xaml.cs:**

```
public object PageContent
{
   get { return PageContentPresenter.Content; }
   set { PageContentPresenter.Content = value; }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<helpers:BasePage x:Name="SlideControl">
    <helpers:BasePage.PageContent>
        <TextBox x:Name="testTb" />
    </helpers:BasePage.PageContent>
</helpers:BasePage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
public MainPage() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.testTb.Text = "test text"; // NullReferenceException!!!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reach testTb you must do

```
var testTb = (TextBox)PageContent.FindName("testTb");
//use testTb as you want.
```

this happens because testTb is in a different scope

**EDIT**:

If your XAML is exactly like this:

```
<helpers:BasePage.PageContent>
    <TextBox x:Name="testTb" />
</helpers:BasePage.PageContent>
```

then you should be able to use TextBox doing this:

```
var testTb = (TextBox)PageContent;
testTb.Text = "Whatever you want to do";
```

**EDIT**

This is a class you need
MyVisualTreeHelper.cs

```
public static class MyVisualTreeHelper
{
    public static T FindVisualChild<T>(this FrameworkElement obj, string childName) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement child = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T && child.Name == childName)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child, childName);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and Here's how you use it:

```
var testTb = SlideControl.PageContent.FindVisualChild<TextBlock>("testTb");

if (testTb != null)
    testTb.Text = "test2";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me... I tried var testTb = (TextBox)SlideControl.PageContent.FindName("testTb"), as I can't directly access PageContent. But there is no Method FindName. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have FindName because your PageContent is Object you should cast it to UiElement or FrameworkElement

Comment: Thanks. It now compiles, but testTb is still null? Btw. what does this mean 'testTb is in a different scope'?

Comment: It's like it resides in an ItemTemplate

Comment: Doesn't it fail because of the same reason my original code failed? The xaml is not yet instantiated and the code accesses it?

Comment: I don't think so because the xaml is instantiated in the InitializeComponent();

Comment: Yeah, you're right: I just found out the same... So, what now? :S Thx!

Comment: Why don't you style your pages on Template property?

Comment: Because I don't just want to style the pages. I want to use my slide-from-left menu (http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.ch/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html) on every page and I don't want to copy the code to every page. That's why I created a custom control.

Comment: can you mail me your source code so I try multiple tests?

Comment: Thanks for the offer! I just sent you the code to your gmail address.

Comment: Thanks for your help via email. The suggestion you described above now works perfectly!